# Que significa "um vídeo produzido a oito mãos"?

Tags: significado

Não entendo que significa "a oito mãos". É feito por quatro pessoas ou só quer dizer coletivamente?

> Alguns exemplos são um desenho publicado num blog na internet, um vídeo produzido a oito mãos de um smartphone e disponibilizado numa plataforma de streaming, textos políticos diagramados em formato de *zine* para serem vendidos ou distribuídos numa banquinha na rua, um livro de poesia de uma editora, um ensaio sobre arte em uma revista mensal.

Comment: filmado por quatro pessoas, ou seja, "por oito mãos" e montado em um só video. Estão falando de realizações artísticas, né?

Comment: que nem aqui: https://www.bheventos.com.br/noticia/11-03-2020-coletivo-nmundo-apresenta-inedito-video-arte-em-programacao-virtual-do-mmgv-memorial-minas-gerais-vale

Comment: Cidade, bem-vindo ao site! Terias um link ou uma referência do texto? O contexto é sumamente importante.

Comment: @Schilive Google retorna "[A Cultura é Livre: Uma História da Resistência Antipropriedade](https://books.google.de/books?id=xnojEAAAQBAJ&pg=PT10&lpg=PT10&dq=%22oito%20m%C3%A3os%22&f=false#v=onepage&q=%22oito%20m%C3%A3os%22&f=false)", de Leonardo Foletto. É só um exemplo dentre vários e, nesse sentido, me parece que o contexto já é dado pela citação da pergunta.

Answer (score 5):

A expressão consagrada é "a quatro mãos", muito usada para composições ou performances musicais para duas pessoas tocando juntas no mesmo instrumento, frequentemente o piano. Mas a expressão com oito não é inédita, inclusive [existe](http://g1.globo.com/sp/campinas-regiao/noticia/2013/01/banda-oito-maos-lanca-disco-alias-com-show-gratuito-em-campinas.html) ou existiu um quarteto musical chamado "Banda Oito Mãos".

Como aparentemente [se trata](https://books.google.de/books?id=xnojEAAAQBAJ&pg=PT10&lpg=PT10&dq=%22oito%20m%C3%A3os%22&f=false#v=onepage&q=%22oito%20m%C3%A3os%22&f=false) apenas de um exemplo hipotético dentre vários, é difícil se dizer com certeza, mas a especificidade do exemplo (não um vídeo qualquer, mas um feito num smartphone e depois *streamed*) e o número relativamente baixo usado, oito, me leva a crer que seriam de fato quatro os autores — já algo como "a cem mãos" eu tenderia a considerar que denota "coletivo", mais que exatos 50 autores.